# Trocar o conteúdo de um painel no JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Na minha aplicação, tenho uma tela principal com um menu. O conteúdo de cada tela do menu deve aparecer dentro de um painel da tela principal, não quero abrir uma tela nova para cada coisa.

O que eu preciso então é trocar o conteúdo do painel da tela principal, igual os fragmentos do Android.

Fiz uma imagem para facilitar o entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi algumas formas de fazer onde eu teria que adicionar elemento por elemento no painel. Eu queria trocar o painel inteiro e não elemento por elemento.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Você não chegou a tentar nada? Não tem algo já feito da sua tela?

Comment: Sim, eu cheguei a fazer alguma coisa. Mas só consegui ou trocar o conteúdo da tela toda ou remover todos os campos do painel e adicionar um por um.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples de se fazer isso é criando paineis diferentes para cada tela, e trocando conforme a necessidade. Usando [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), a troca fica mais simples do que ter que ficar invalidando e redesenhando a tela toda hora, ou [criando frames internos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)(o que acho bem nais dispendioso de se controlar do que com paineis).

Você inicialmente precisa criar os paineis, como se fosse os "fragmentos" de tela, depois nomeá-los para que o `CardLayout` consiga identificar eles entre si.

Veja o exemplo abaixo adaptado dos exemplos da documentação, para se ter uma noção de como você pode fazer:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
    final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";
    JPanel cards;

    public CardLayoutDemo() {

        setTitle("CardLayoutDemo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem submenu01 = new JMenuItem("Painel de botoes");
        submenu01.setActionCommand(BUTTONPANEL);
        submenu01.addActionListener(new ChangeCardlayoutListener());
        JMenuItem submenu02 = new JMenuItem("Painel de texto");
        submenu02.setActionCommand(TEXTPANEL);
        submenu02.addActionListener(new ChangeCardlayoutListener());
        menu.add(submenu01);
        menu.add(submenu02);
        menubar.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        // cria o painel de botoes
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
        // cria o painel de campos de texto
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
        card2.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));
        card2.add(new JTextField("TextField2", 20));

        // este painel é quem será o container para o cardlayout
        // organizar os outros dois paineis
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
        cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);

        getContentPane().add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class ChangeCardlayoutListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
            cl.show(cards, (String) evt.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(CardLayoutDemo::new);
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que, obrigatoriamente, um dos painéis precisa começar visível, mas creio que isso não seja um problema. E se os paineis forem muito complexos, o ideal é criar uma classe para cada um que estenda `JPanel`, e instancia-los ao adicionar no `CardLayout`.

---

#### Referência:

- [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Com isso eu consigo separar os painéis em classes?

Comment: @JônatasTrabucoBelotti veja o ultimo parágrafo da resposta.

Comment: Maravilha. Vou tentar aqui, já já falo o resultado.

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!